# How can I store clicked QPushbuttons

Tags: qt

I created a bunch of Qpushbuttons with QT designer, after click more than one button I Want to take these buttons and transfer other function to change these buttons' lets say the color properties. Is it possible to store these clicked buttons and use them? If possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

You could add pointers to the clicked buttons to a `QList`, `QVector` or some other container type, and pass that to the code that needs to change them.

Without more details about your actual code, it's hard to be more specific than this, sorry.

Comment: QVector<QPushButton*> buttonList;

Comment: QVector<QPushButton*> buttonList;                                         QPushButton* clickedButton= (QPushButton*)(sender());                                                buttonList[i]=clickedButton;//gives "lvalue required as left operant of assignment" error                                                    buttonLis[m]->setPalette(QPalette(QColor(255,0,0)));//gives error              and how can we use that Qvector

Comment: [Read the documentation for QVector](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html) and use the `at` function to access, the `insert` function to insert (or the others). `QList` or one of its variants is probably better for your needs. And post another question (with more details including **exact** error messages) if you can't figure it out. Or edit this one to include all the details.

Comment: ´QVector<QPushButton*> buttonList;´ ´void SeatReservImpl::selectSeat(){´ ´QPushButton* clickedButton= (QPushButton*)(sender());´ ´buttonList.append(clickedButton);´//

Comment: please stop pasting code in comments. Edit your question (with **exact** error messages if any) if you want to clarify

Comment: I am sorry for the ,inconvenience